# JavaFX KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED being executed for everything EXCEPT arrow keys - Why?

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent, arrow-keys

I am adding my event handler through:
`getCorrelatingView().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, getKeyEventHandler());`

And `getKeyEventHandler()` is:

```
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> getKeyEventHandler() {
    return keyEvent -> {
        System.out.println("Key received + " + keyEvent.toString());
    }
}
```

`getCorrelatingView()` does have focus, due to the fact that the key received message is printed out upon pressing every key except arrow keys. This includes letters and arrow keys **with** modifers (such as `Control + Up`). `Up`, by itself, does not trigger the key event.

In addition, based on research, I have added:

```
getCorrelatingView().setFocusTraversable(false);
getCorrelatingView().requestFocus();
```

to my `initialize` method to the controller of `getCorrelatingView()`. Those have made no difference.

**How can I listen to non-modified arrow keys within my `getKeyEventHandler()`?**

Comment: What are you registering the listener on, and how are you registering it?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: @James_D With your question in mind, I did some testing. Within the question, `getCorrelatingView()` returns a BorderPane. When the event handler is applied to the BorderPane, arrow keys are not listened for (and the question asks why). However, when I apply the same event handler to a TabPane that is the center of the BorderPane, it detects arrow keys.

Comment: Try `KeyReleased`.